# View not reflecting data coming from User Defaults

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, state, userdefaults

I have created a singleton class called `AppSecurityStore` which currently only holds a boolean property to store a setting value.

```
final class AppSecurityStore {
    static let shared = AppSecurityStore()
    
    private init() { }
    
    var isAppLockEnabled: Bool {
        get {
            UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "AppLock")
        }
        set {
            UserDefaults.standard.setValue(newValue, forKey: "AppLock")
        }
    }
}
```

I have a view where I toggle the value for this property.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var appSecurityStore: AppSecurityStore
    
    init(appSecurityStore: AppSecurityStore) {
        self.appSecurityStore = appSecurityStore
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Section {
                Toggle("App Lock", isOn: $appSecurityStore.isAppLockEnabled)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I change the toggle value, it does get saved in User Defaults properly. However if I background the app and bring it back to the foreground, it doesn't reflect the updated state. It still shows the previous value!

[Gif demonstrating the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYeuM.gif)

The `appSecurityStore` variable inside the view is a `@State` variable so I'm not sure why it doesn't persist the updated value.

Any help to resolve this is appreciated.

I have uploaded a demo project [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1M-MN8-fXsae-MKt4nm8Yn7vOm60xUTk6/view?usp=sharing).

**Important**: I cannot use environment objects in this app due to decisions being made to not use them since they don't play well with MVVM.

Comment: Note, `@State` is for value types, eg `struct`, not for reference types, eg `class`.
 You could try using `@Observable`

Comment: Use AppStorage nothing is telling SwiftUI to redraw here. You should also look at the Apple SwiftUI tutorials State isn’t for ObservableObjects

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine Thank you. I overlooked that one. Although even after adding `@Observable` to the `AppSecurityStore` class, the problem still persists.

Comment: It doesn’t make any difference to the answers but for the future you might wish to consider that UserDefaults is not a secure storage and can be read transparently from a backup or directly from device. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68022172/why-is-using-userdefaults-to-store-sensitive-information-on-ios-not-safe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a new property wrapper called @AppStorage for this use case, you may want to check it out [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/appstorage):

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
  @AppStorage("AppLock") private var appLock = false
  var body: some View {
    ...
    Toggle("App Lock", isOn: $appLock)
  }
}
```

**Updated**: In case you want to make it a class for passing-around purposes, you can try this approach. Notice `objectWillChange.send()` means that whenever `isAppLockEnabled` changes, it will notify any subscribed views that need to be refreshed.

```swift
final class AppSecurityStore: ObservableObject {
    static let shared = AppSecurityStore()

    private init() { }

    var isAppLockEnabled: Bool {
        get {
            UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "AppLock")
        }
        set {
            UserDefaults.standard.setValue(newValue, forKey: "AppLock")
            objectWillChange.send()
        }
    }
}
```

`AppSecurityStore` need to be a @StateObject too, check this [document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/stateobject).

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var appSecurityStore: AppSecurityStore = .shared
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm aware of the `@AppStore` property wrapper. But I need to access this boolean value from elsewhere in my real app. So I have to save it in a dedicated object and pass it around.

Comment: @cenisuru AppStorage can be used anywhere including inside an ObservableObject

Comment: @cenisuru UserDefault often needs some time to save data on its internal storage. i,e, the app runs on debug mode -> turn on the toggle -> force shut down the app intermediately. By doing that, the UserDefault will not work. Or AFAIK, no local storage does.

Comment: @son You're right. I ran it on the device in release mode and it seems to work fine now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to observe the changes, for the moment you pass a copy of the `AppSecurityStore` not a reference.
Conform to `ObservableObject` and use the `@Published`:

```
final class AppSecurityStore: ObservableObject {
    static let shared = AppSecurityStore()
    
    private init() { }

    @Published var isAppLockEnabled: Bool {
        get {
            UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "AppLock")
        }
        set {
            UserDefaults.standard.setValue(newValue, forKey: "AppLock")
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject private var appSecurityStore: AppSecurityStore
    
    init(appSecurityStore: AppSecurityStore = .shared) {
        self.appSecurityStore = appSecurityStore
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Section {
                Toggle("App Lock", isOn: $appSecurityStore.isAppLockEnabled)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### Update:

Initiate `isAppLockEnabled` in `init` and use the `didSet` to update the changes

```
final class AppSecurityStore: ObservableObject {
    static let shared = AppSecurityStore()
    
    @Published var isAppLockEnabled: Bool {
        didSet {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(isAppLockEnabled, forKey: "AppLock")
        }
    }
    
    private init() {
        self.isAppLockEnabled = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "AppLock")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. But it gives an error `Property wrapper cannot be applied to a computed property`.

Comment: Thanks. That indeed makes the error go away. However I noticed a strange randomly occurring issue. Please see [here](https://i.imgur.com/2ngyN39.gif). The bool value sometimes doesn't seem to be persisted. If I turn it on, relaunch the app, the toggle still shows off state.